# Getting multiple results instead of one in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a simple code: `Exam::find(1)->with('questions')->get()`.
I have a many to many relation with exam and question. I am expecting one exam with `id=1` and all the related questions with it but I am getting all the exams with this code. What is wrong here?

**Updated:** I have added the tinker output, I hope it will help.

Here is the tinker output:

```
>>> App\Exam::find(1)->with('questions')->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4263
     all: [
       App\Exam {#4212
         id: 1,
         title: "Exam 1",
         duration: 20,
         created_at: "2020-10-08 07:09:09",
         updated_at: "2020-10-08 07:09:09",
         mcqs: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#151
           all: [
             App\Question {#4273
               id: 1,
               question: "First Question",
               a: "option a",
               b: "option b",
               c: "option c",
               d: "option d",
             },
             App\Question {#4274
               id: 2,
               question: "Second Question",
               a: "option a",
               b: "option b",
               c: "option c",
               d: "option d",
             },
             App\Question {#4275
               id: 3,
               question: "Third Question",
               a: "option a",
               b: "option b",
               c: "option c",
               d: "option d",
             },
           ],
         },
       },
       App\Question {#4255
         id: 2,
         title: "Exam 2",
         duration: 12,
         created_at: "2020-10-08 07:09:24",
         updated_at: "2020-10-08 07:09:24",
         mcqs: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4264
           all: [
             App\Question {#4276
               id: 4,
               question: "First Question",
               a: "option a",
               b: "option b",
               c: "option c",
               d: "option d",
             },
             App\Question {#4277
               id: 5,
               question: "Second Question",
               a: "option a",
               b: "option b",
               c: "option c",
               d: "option d",
             },
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: `all the exams with this code`... Do you have more than one record with `id=1` in the database?

Comment: what's your expect the response?

Comment: the expected response would be `the exam with this code`. (only one exam). But now you updated your question I understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```php
$exam = Exam::with('questions')->where('id', 1)->first();
$questions = $exam->questions;
```

The `->get()` method always returns a collection. If you need to grab only one record `->first()` will do the trick.

This code will work too:

```php
$exam = Exam::with('questions')->find(1);
```

`->find(1)` is just an alias to `->where('id', 1)->first()`

--- edited

The `with` method will not work into your statement:

```php
$exams = App\Exam::find(1)->with('questions')->get()
```

Remember, `find(1)` is an alias to `->where('id', 1)->first()`. At this point, you are calling the function on the `Exam` model. To make `with` work correctly:

```php
$exams = App\Exam::with('questions')->find(1)->get()
```

Also, if you use `->get()` at the end, Laravel will transform your object model into a collection with one item. You can just ignore it at this time if you want only one item.

```php
$exam = App\Exam::with('questions')->find(1);
```

One of the ways to load questions after retrieving it from DB is to use the `load` function.

```php
// grab one record from database
$exam = App\Exam::find(1);
// load questions
$exam->load('questions');
// assign to variable a collections of questions
$questions = $exam->questions;
```

Laravel will autoload questions automatically if the relationships are correctly configured. The following code will work too:

```php
$exam = App\Exam::find(1);
dd($exam->questions);
```

I don't know why but I do prefer to use this sintax:

```php
$exam = App\Exam::with('questions')->where('id', 1)->first();
```

Perhaps it is because it's more close to SQL.

Comment: I tried your code, they are giving the same result as my code gave me. It is returning all the exams with questions.
I had a mistake in my question, the relationship is many to many, not one to many. Can you use this to help me?

Comment: Can you `dd($exam)`? I'm pretty sure that if you use the `->first()` method, you will have one object of `Exam`, the object with id number 1. This object will have related questions autoloaded. If you update your question with the model relationships and the table schema, it will help too.

Comment: I have updated the question with tinker output. Have a look.

Comment: I just updated the answer. Are your relationships configured correctly?

Comment: `$exam = App\Exam::with('questions')->where('id', 1)->first();` this is the code I figured out and it is working!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
class Exam extends Model 
{
  public function questions()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Exam::class);
  }
}


class Question extends Model
{
  public function exams {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Example::class);
  }
}


$exam = Exam::find(1);
$exam->questions;
```

It should work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Exam::find(1)->loadMissing('questions')
It should work

Comment: Same output mentioned in the question. Not helping.